# define-key: Symbol's function definition is void: lisp-interaction-mode-map

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've got a snippet I want to bind to a key:

```el
(define-key (lisp-interaction-mode-map) (kdb "C-c e")
  (let ((result (eval (read (buffer-substring
                             (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol))))))
    (goto-char (point-at-eol))
    (insert (format " ; %s" result))))
```

however, when `C-c v` that in `*scratch*`, I get

```
define-key: Symbol's function definition is void: lisp-interaction-mode-map
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have parentheses around `lisp-interaction-mode-map`, which Lisp interprets to mean that you want to call the function named `lisp-interaction-mode-map`.  Instead, you want to use it as variable.

I also did some other edits you'll need to get what you have to work.  I assumed you wrote `read` in order to prompt for a user-inputted string:

```
(define-key lisp-interaction-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-e")
  (lambda (result)
    (interactive (list (read-from-minibuffer (buffer-substring (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol)))))
    (goto-char (point-at-eol))
    (insert (format " ; %s" result))))
```

Comment: Nope, it shouldn't. It should eval the current line of elisp and add the result at the end of the line.

Comment: Have you tried just doing `C-j`?  It puts the result on the next line, but still...

Comment: Huh. What function is bound to that hotkey? It's bound to a `paredit` function.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the normal form?

```
(define-key lisp-interaction-mode-map [(control e)] 'eval-defun)
```